# Match keys in json file with csv files

Tags: python, key, match

I'm new to programing and I'm currently working on my thesis.

I'm working with multiple csv files and a json file containing genes with amino acid changes involved in antibiotic resistance. The csv files are formatted like this:

```
Gene_Aminoacids Filename
gyrA_S95T   SRR9851427
tlyA_L11L   SRR9851427
katG_R463L  SRR9851427
```

In the json file the genes are present as keys, and the corresponding antibiotic which it effects are set as values.

Ex small part of json file.

```
"gyrA_A74S" : ["Quinolones"],
"gyrA_D89X" : ["Quinolones"],
"tlyA_C-83T" : ["Capreomycin"]
"katG_R104Q" : ["Isoniazid"],
"katG_S315I" : ["Isoniazid"],
"katG_S315N" : ["Isoniazid"],
  etc....
```

What I'm interested in is finding matching genes from the json file in the csv files. The output should contain the keys, which is the genes, the corresponding antibiotic and in the filename(file) that contains the a.a change.

Ex of the wanted output

```
 Gene_Aminoacids Antibiotic  Filename` 
 "katG_R104Q" : ["Isoniazid"], SRR9851427
```

So far this is the code that I have written and I have looked into similar issues but they didn't work on my data.

```
def retrive_rest_mutations(jsonfile): 
with open(jsonfile) as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)    
    return(data.keys())

mutation_keys = retrive_rest_mutations("tb_TEST.json")

 ##Read & set path to folder containing a.a changes 

 path = "Replaced_P_G.ann.vcf"
 samp = glob.glob(path + "/*_G.P.vcf_replaced.txt")

###Read text files
result = []

def read_text_file(file_path):
     with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
          print(f.read())

##iterate through all files
def all_files():
for file in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        file_path = f"{samp}/{file}"
        read_text_file(file_path)
print("\n")
```

I'm uncertain on how to do the matching between the json file and the multiple csv files and there might be a simple solution to my issue.

Dose anyone maybe have a suggestion, or what I should look into to get the new output containing the Genes + Antibiotic + Filename?

Best regards

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Many questions arise.
Can a same gene e.g `gyrA_S95T` appear in several CSV files ?
Then we have to know more about data volume.
How many CSV files do you have ?
How many CSV lines (total of all CSV files) do you have ?
What is the size of you JSON file ? How many lookups are you going to do ?
Depending on the asnwers a solution could be to build an adequate data structure in memory or populate a database.

Comment: What you are trying to do would be quite simple with pandas (`pd.read_csv`, `pd.read_json`, `pd.merge`), but you really need to provide a better description of your problem, and provide a consistent subset of your data (meaning that the Gene_Aminoacids in the first file can be found in the second). And, your python sample code is not properly indented. Since indentation carries meaning in python, it is not clear what the program is doing (or at least ambiguous).

Comment: You're correct @fbattello , the same gene can appear in several CSV-files. In total I have 163 CSV-files and each files contains between 1-22 a.a changes. The json-file sizes is 7,9 kB. I'm interested in looping through all of my CSV-files and match the keys that are present in both files into a new output file.

Comment: @DanielSchneider, thank you. I will look into pandas and pd.merge more specific.

Comment: Are your CSV files used as a kind of reference data ?
Let's say that today you have a json file and you want to run your process (against a set of CSV files).
Let's say that tomorrow you'll have another json file. Will the CSV files remain the same ?

Comment: @fbattello, yes its a reference data so the results will stay the same. The files are downloaded from ENA and I will run my script to verify that I get the same results.

Comment: In this case it could be valuable to use a database. A SQL database or a key-value database.
It has many advantages. Data are not volatile, it persists from an execution to another.
You can query data by using a query language as SQL.
You can work with far much more data than your memory can hold.
Data are indexed meaning better performances. 
May be some genetic-dedicated database exist as well as a domain specific language ?

Answer (score 0):

Let me introduce you to `Pandas`

> pandas is a software library written for the Python programming
> language for data manipulation and analysis

Here is the approch

*#step0 ---> raeding csv file

#step1 -->reading json in text file

#step2  --->merging csv & Json

#step3  ---> filling empty values with above values(just for example)

#Final step - concate columns *

Simply read your files with pandas and make changes accordingly

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df =pd.read_csv(r"Kristina Cvetanoska.csv")
#print(df)


data = pd.read_csv('sam.txt', sep=':',header =None)

dfs= pd.concat([df, data], axis=1)

dfs=dfs.fillna(method='ffill')
  

dfs['final']= dfs['Filename']+' '+ dfs[0]+' ' +dfs[1]

print(dfs['final'])
```

your output will something looks like

```
0      SRR9851427 gyrA_A74S   ["Quinolones"],
1      SRR9851427 gyrA_D89X   ["Quinolones"],
2      SRR9851427 tlyA_C-83T   ["Capreomycin"],
3      SRR9851427 katG_R104Q   ["Isoniazid"],     ####<-- Here is sample
4      SRR9851427 katG_S315I   ["Isoniazid"],
5      SRR9851427 katG_S315N   ["Isoniazid"]
```

Name: final, dtype: object

Comment: Hi Bhargav, 
Thank you for taking the time to write the script and it works fine, but the output I get is not the keys + values which are present in both the csv files and the json file. Im only interested in files (csv-files) with the same keys as the json-file.